# How do I block a specific image using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there any way to deny access to a specific image in .htaccess alone? If I were to block and image such as "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" how would I format it?

I would also like to add that I don't own said image, I'm trying to block an off-site image in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an [Apache Expression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) (Apache 2.4+):

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/tags/smiley.gif'">
Require all denied
</If>
```

**UPDATE:** I initially thought your reference to `w3schools.com` was just a misleading example, but if this is really an "off-site image", as stated in your updated question, then you can't block a request to `externalsite.example` in the `.htaccess` file at `example.com`. Your `example.com/.htaccess` file naturally only processes requests that target `example.com`.

You need to modify the HTML source so that the link to the external site doesn't appear on the page in the first place.

Comment: I don't own smiley.gif, I am wondering how to block the image when it's on another site to prevent it from displaying on mine.

Comment: Oh OK, I thought that was just a bad example! You can't block a request that targets a website you don't control in `.htaccess`! You need to prevent the `img` HTML element being generated in the HTML source to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can't on a server block an image on ***another*** server. 
If you control the HTML that requests the image you can block it in your HTML code - but .htaccess has nothing to do with it.